# How to programmatically check if an Android device supports Bluetooth HID profile?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

On some Android device, after I successfully connected the game handle, the handle can work properly, but some devices can be connected to the handle successfully, the handle did not work properly。I could not find any standard API in Android to check for HID profile support. Is there any way (direct or indirect) by which one can determine this programmatically?